# JavaScript in webView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

How to add scroll listener in JS cod for android webView?

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);           
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                injectJavascript();
            }
        });

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(DirUtils.getCssImagesPath(mActivity), dataStr, "application/xhtml+xml", "UTF-8", null);
```

The next method split html page. But how to fix horizontal scrolling? when I make a left\right swipe, I want to see next\prev page. Thanks!

```
    public void injectJavascript() {
    String js = "javascript:function initialize() { " +
            "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
            "var ourH = window.innerHeight; " +
            "var ourW = window.innerWidth; " +
            "var fullH = d.offsetHeight; " +
            "var pageCount = Math.floor(fullH/ourH)+1;" +
            "var currentPage = 0; " +
           // "$('body').animate({scrollLeft: window.innerWidth*<currentPage>});" +
            "var newW = pageCount*ourW; " +
            "d.style.height = ourH+'px';" +
            "d.style.width = newW+'px';" +
            "d.style.webkitColumnGap = '2px'; " +
            "d.style.margin = 10; " +
            "d.style.webkitColumnCount = pageCount;" +
            "}";
    webView.loadUrl(js);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:initialize()");
}
```

Comment: Add interface and then get your values in code

Comment: Can you customize this method in JS interface for it?

 @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html){

    }